# @Test annotation is running first for all the tests in testNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I have couple of test case under my testng.xml. My testng.xml looks like this below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="AutomationPractice" parallel="none">
  <test name="Logins">
    <classes>
      <class name="newMavenProject.Gmail_Login_Firefox"/>
      <class name="newMavenProject.Facebook_Login_Chrome"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Logins -->
</suite> <!-- AutomationPractice -->
```

In both of my tests, I have @BeforeTest, @Test and @AfterTest annotations. When I run the testng.xml as testNGSuite. I see that the browser gets open for both the tests (@BeforeTest) simultaneously and then Gmail_Login test will run @Test annotation. Then Facebook_Login_Chrome will run its @Test annotation. And then my Gmail_Login test will run @AfterTest annotation (close the browser) and then my Facebook_Login_Chrome test will run the @AfterTest annotation (close browser).

How can I make it possible that my Gmail_Login Test runs completely (@BeforeTest, @Test, @AfterTest) and then my Facebook_Login_Chrome Test runs completely(@BeforeTest, @Test, @AfterTest).

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you are using to simulate this issue ? Also when you print out the thread ids, what do you see ? TestNG shouldnt be running anything in parallel, unless and until it is explicitly configured. So you might want to add the printing thread id logic and share the output. Also please include the TestNG version that you are using. Latest released version as of today is `6.13.1`

Comment: You should use beforemethod and aftermethod which run immediately surrounding the test method. Beforetest and aftertest are run for the test tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `<test>` tag is executed, it runs all methods, annotated `@BeforeTest` from all the included classes.

It looks as though you need to annotate the set-up and tear-down methods with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations.

According to [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations):

> `@BeforeTest`: The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag is run.
>
> `@AfterTest`: The annotated method will be run after all the test
>   methods belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag have run.
>
> `@BeforeClass`: The annotated method will be run before the first test
>   method in the current class is invoked.
>
> `@AfterClass`: The annotated method will be run after all the test
>   methods in the current class have been run.